# How do I create a Line graph with my Data?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, graph, line

I have a CSV file which contains two columns. First column contains a date in the format 01/01/1969 and second column has an average house price for that month. The data I have ranges from 01/04/1969 to the same date in 2019 for a total of 613 entries in the dataframe. I want to create a line graph which represents the average house price per year. So far I have this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('ScottishAveragePrices.csv')

df.groupby(['Date']).mean().sort_values('AveragePrice')
```

The output is :

```
                 AveragePrice
 Date                     
01/04/1968    2844.980688
01/05/1968    2844.980688
01/06/1968    2844.980688
01/10/1968    2921.049691
01/11/1968    2921.049691
                 ...
01/04/2019  150825.247700
01/09/2018  151465.715100
01/10/2018  151499.207500
01/07/2018  151874.694900
01/08/2018  152279.438800

[613 rows x 1 columns]
```

Im just not sure how to tranfer this data into a line graph. Sorry if the formatting of this post is wrong I'm very new to the forum.

Thanks

Comment: Use matplotlib and plt.plot plot(x, y)        https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html

Answer (score 0):

Name the df and then plot it with matplotlib:

```
df_2 = df.groupby(['Date']).mean().sort_values('AveragePrice')

df_2.plot(y="AveragePrice")
```

Make sure you also have the matplotlib magic function in your code:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: Im using Spyder and when I try to insert %matplotlib inline I get a syntax error

Comment: Also thank you very much this has worked but the dates alone the x axis are all overlapping. Do yo know how to fix this?

Comment: Okay, that may only be applicable for Jupyter notebook then. On your second point, try plotting the dates in a different form

Comment: Do you mean to replace the line df_2.plot(y="AveragePrice") with the new suggestion entirely? If I do this I get the error : name 'mdates' is not defined

Comment: Try this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/recipes/common_date_problems.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('ScottishAveragePrices.csv')
df = df.groupby(['Date']).mean().sort_values('AveragePrice')
plt.plot(df['Date'], df['AveragePrice'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response this worked really well for the graph but the dates are overallping so much they are just a big black line at the bottom. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: Try adding this line to the code:
`plt.xticks(rotation=90)`

Comment: I think because there is a date for every month between 1969 and 2019 the amount of text on the screen is impossible to organise efficiently. Adding this line just created a further two lines of black craziness.